# Heroku app not found when URL isn't prefixed with www

Tags: url, heroku, dns, web, hosting

I have a Rails app hosted on Heroku, and when I don't prefix the domain in the browser with the www, I get a no application found error. Like this,

```
<domain-name>.com
```

causes the error but
    www..com works fine.

How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your application setup to respond to `<domain-name>.com`? Check with `$ heroku domains`, do you see `*.<domain-name>.com` or `<domain-name>.com` there? Is DNS set to forward that domain to your Heroku app?